# Project Task Manager - Python, Pysimplegui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am in the process of trying to learn python and some of its libraries. I thought building a task manager for my job would be a fun & useful project for me to work on in my free time. I have gotten to the point of having a very minimal home screen but I cant seem to get my buttons to work. Right now I am stuck on getting my "projects" button to open a new window. I have tried following the example on pysimplegui git page but cannot seem to resolve this. I think it would be helpful to get some additional input or at least a new set of eyes on what I have written so far.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib as mp

sg.theme("default1")


def make_homeWin():
    Mbw = 24 #Main Screen Button Width
    Mbh = 6 #Main Screen Button Height
    BFsize = 14 #Button Font Size
    
    #Layout of the window
    layout = [[sg.Text('Test Operations Dashbaord - Troy, MI',font=('Bahnschrift Light Condensed',24), size=(1000,2), justification='center')],
              [sg.Button('Projects', size=(Mbw,Mbh), font=('Bahnschrift Light Condensed',BFsize)), sg.Button('Schedule', size=(Mbw,Mbh), font=('Bahnschrift Light Condensed',BFsize), pad=(40,0))],
              [sg.Text('_'*150, pad=(20,(10,25)))],
              [sg.Button('Tools', size=(Mbw,Mbh), font=('Bahnschrift Light Condensed',BFsize)),
               sg.Button('Calibration', size=(Mbw,Mbh), font=('Bahnschrift Light Condensed',BFsize), pad=((40,20),0)),
               sg.Button('Photos', size=(Mbw,Mbh), font=('Bahnschrift Light Condensed',BFsize), pad=((20,40),0)),
               sg.Button('Quality',size=(Mbw,Mbh), font=('Bahnschrift Light Condensed',BFsize))]]
    #Create window
    return sg.Window('Home', layout, size=(1000, 700), finalize=True)



def make_projWin():
    Mbw = 24 #Main Screen Button Width
    Mbh = 6 #Main Screen Button Height
    BFsize = 14 #Button Font Size
    
    layout2 = [[sg.Button('New Project', size=(Mbw,Mbh), font=('Bahnschrift Light Condensed',BFsize), pad=(40,0))]]
            
    return sg.Window('Project Manager', layout2, size=(1000, 700), finalize=True)



def make_schWindow():
    layout3 =[[]]
    
    return sg.Window('Schedule Manager', layout3, size=(1000,700), finalize=True)



window1, window2 = make_homeWin(), None # Start off with homeWindow Open

#Event Loop to process "events" and get the values of the inputs
while True:             # Event Loop
    window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        window.close()
        if window == window2:       # if closing win 2, mark as closed
            window2 = None
        elif window == window1:     # if closing win 1, exit program
            break
        elif event == 'Projects' and not window2:
            window2 = make_projWin()
window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your event loop, after reading the windows, all the code is under `if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED`, and thus, on any other event, nothing will happen. You need to move `elif event == 'Projects'` one indent to the left. This small change will make it work:

```
while True:  # Event Loop
    window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        window.close()
        if window == window2:  # if closing win 2, mark as closed
            window2 = None
        elif window == window1:  # if closing win 1, exit program
            break
    elif event == 'Projects' and not window2:
        window2 = make_projWin()
window.close()
```

A couple of tips:

Instead of specifying (mostly the same) font for each button separately, you can set a font to be used in your window on calling `sg.Window()` like this:

```
return sg.Window('Home', layout, size=(1000, 700),
                 font=('Bahnschrift Light Condensed', BFsize), finalize=True)
```

and only set a font in those buttons that need another one.

Instead of `[sg.Text('_'*150, pad=(20,(10,25)))]`, you may want to use `[sg.HorizontalSeparator()]` that will automatically stretch over the whole width of your window (or you can set its size if you want to have it shorter). This makes the code more universal and will also work if you decide to change your font, size of the buttons etc. Notice that with some themes incl. `default1`, you will need to set the color of the horizontal separator as otherwise it will be invisible; use, e.g., `sg.HorizontalSeparator(color='black')`.

The size of your first `Text()` element is quite overwhelming: `size=(1000, 2)` means 1000 characters wide.

Often, it comes out nicely if you *don't* set size of the window; in that case, the window will be sized automatically to fit the layout.

Last but not least, PySimpleGUI's idea is to make coding GUI as simple as possible, i.e., only set those options that need to be other than default. That way, you can achieve a very compact code.

So, your first window could be something like this:

```
def make_homeWin():
    button_size = (24, 6)
    BFsize = 14  # Button Font Size

    # Layout of the window
    layout = [[sg.Text('Test Operations Dashboard - Troy, MI', 
                       font=('Bahnschrift Light Condensed', 24),
                       key='title', justification='center')],
              [sg.Button('Projects', size=button_size),
               sg.Button('Schedule', size=button_size)],
              [sg.HorizontalSeparator(color='black')],
              [sg.Button('Tools', size=button_size),
               sg.Button('Calibration', size=button_size),
               sg.Button('Photos', size=button_size),
               sg.Button('Quality', size=button_size)]]
    window = sg.Window('Home', layout, font=('Bahnschrift Light Condensed', BFsize), 
                       element_padding=(10, 10), finalize=True)
    window['title'].expand(expand_x=True)  # making the title text window-wide
    return window
```

resulting in
[image: PySimpleGUI - example]